# Retrofit2 doesn't send POST data

Tags: java, android, post, retrofit, retrofit2

Sorry if my English is bad! I use retrofit 2 to receive data dependent on POST data. I receive data from the server, but have a problem with sending data. I'd tried to use different annotations (@Field, @Body with Object, @Body with HashMap data), but each of them didn't work.
Here is my Java code:

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.retrofitpostdatagetjson"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

**APIClient.java**

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class APIClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://myurl.ru/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**ApiUtils.java**

```
public class ApiUtils {

    private ApiUtils() {}

    public static APIInterface getAPIService() {

        return APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
    }
}
```

**APIInterface.java**

```
import com.test.retrofitpostdatagetjson.model.DataResponse;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface APIInterface {
    @POST("test_json_with_post")
    Call<DataResponse> createData(@Body DataResponse data);

}
```

**DataResponse.java**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class DataResponse implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("numb")
    @Expose
    private int numb;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("emp")
    @Expose
    public String value;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    public String status;

    public DataResponse(int numb, String name) {
        this.numb = numb;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getNumb() {
        return numb;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setNumb(int numb) {
        this.numb = numb;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DataResponse{" +
                "numb=" + numb +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", value='" + value + '\'' +
                ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import com.test.retrofitpostdatagetjson.api.APIInterface;
import com.test.retrofitpostdatagetjson.model.DataResponse;
import static com.test.retrofitpostdatagetjson.api.ApiUtils.getAPIService;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    APIInterface apiInterface;
    int numb = 0;
    String name = "test row";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        apiInterface = getAPIService();

        if (CommonMethod.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this))
            sendPost(numb, name);
        else
            CommonMethod.showAlert("Internet Connectivity Failure", MainActivity.this);

    }

    private void sendPost(int numb, String name) {

        final DataResponse data = new DataResponse(numb, name);
        Log.w("retroTest", "sent    -->  " + data.toString());
        Call<DataResponse> call1 = apiInterface.createData(data);
        call1.enqueue(new Callback<DataResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DataResponse> call, Response<DataResponse> response) {
                DataResponse dataResponse = response.body();
                if (dataResponse != null) {
                    Log.w("retroTest", "received    -->  " + dataResponse.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DataResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onFailure called ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                call.cancel();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Here is my Logs:**

```
W/retroTest: sent  -->  DataResponse{numb=0, name='test row', value='null', status='null'}
W/retroTest: received  -->  DataResponse{numb=0, name='null', value='null', status='2'}
```

**my PHP file on the server:**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);

$numb = $input['numb'];
$name = $input['name'];

if (isset($_POST['numb']) && !empty($_POST['numb'])) {   
  $numb = $_POST['numb']; }
if (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])) {   
  $name = $_POST['name']; }

if (!$numb) {
$json = json_encode( array(
"emp" => $name,
"status" => "2"));
} else {
$json = json_encode( array(
"emp" => "nothing",
"status" => "2"));
}

$myfile = fopen("testfile.txt", "w");
fwrite($myfile, $inputJSON);
fwrite($myfile, "\n");
fwrite($myfile, $numb);
fwrite($myfile, "\n");
fwrite($myfile, $name);
fclose($myfile);


echo $json;
?>
```

File testfile.txt is also empty, but when I try to send POST by Postman everything is working!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the url in postman same as "/test_json_with_post"? Also, I dont see the code written for "sent  -->" log

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a POST request using retrofit 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34776213/how-to-make-a-post-request-using-retrofit-2)

Comment: uneq95, yes the url in postman is the same, also I receive data from it in my app, the problem is only in sending data from the app. About "sent -->" log - sorry, i've changed these rows after paste code of MainActivity into my question. Fixed it now.

Comment: Prim, answers on that question didn't help me, maybe the reason of my problem in my code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found out the reason of my problem.. It's so simple.. It's all about a slash at the end of url.
I use index.php, so when I send POST to my url address I should end it with slash.

Instead this:

```
 @POST("test_json_with_post")
```

I should write this:

```
 @POST("test_json_with_post/")
```

in my APIInterface.java. And everything is working!

Hope, it helps someone someday)

Comment: Thank you! :) I'm so happy that my help is useful!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending body as JsonObject? 
Always works for me. If not, then i'd assume there is something wrong with the backend port

Something like this:

```
public interface APIInterface {
    @POST("test_json_with_post")
    Call<DataResponse> createData(@Body JsonObject data);

}
```

```
JsonObject obj = new Gson().toJson(yourDataObject);
...
apiInterface.createData(obj);
```

Comment: I couldn't do exactly the way you wrote, because Android Studio told me "incompatible types. Required: com.google.gson.JsonObject Found: java.lang.String". I do this: JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(data)); But it still haven't solved my problem

Comment: @Maria JSONObject and JsonObject are two different objects. First is default java library implementation, second is Gson library implementation. You should probably use the second one. Check your imports and get rid of JSONObject :)

Comment: Yury Dombaev, I understand, that JSONObject and JsonObject are two different objects. As you see in my comment I try to use com.google.gson.JsonObject and recieve a mistake (incompatible types), because the method toJson(Object src) returns String.. And I don't understand to fix it correctly)

Comment: @Maria Oh, sorry, seems like I gave you the wrong method. Can you try this one? 

`JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(javaObject); JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonElement; `