# How to pass a POST array object using java - retrofit 2

Tags: java, api, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit 2 with Java. How can I send a post request with these two keys (url, name):

```
{ "frames": [{
        "url": "string",
        "name": "string"
    }]
}
```

```
public class ExteriorPayLoad {

    private final String url;
    private final String name;
    
    public ExteriorPayLoad(String url, String name) {
        this.url = url;
        this.name = name;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt find the class ExteriorPayLoad in the retrofit2 API source code.

You can't send a post request using this class ExteriorPayLoad. You must specify the body.

Here is a link that show an example to make a post request using Retrofit2 :
[example of post request using Retrofit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34776213/how-to-make-a-post-request-using-retrofit-2)

Thanks.